# Rails 4 data: {confirm:} not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%=link_to "Delete", :action => 'destroy_password', :id => p.id, :job => @job, data: {confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete this password?'} %>
```

This link deletes the data but doesn't prompt to confirm. Any ideas why the confirm is not working? This is Rails 4

It is passing the data through as a parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%=link_to "Delete", {:action => 'destroy_password', :id => p.id, :job => @job},:method => :delete ,data: {confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete this password?'} %>
```

Comment: Turbolinks isn't necessary here, just the JavaScript library included in `application` by default.

Comment: i had the exact same issue and i solved it by adding turbolinks again. Maybe rails use turbolinks as default for that notice

Comment: Turbolinks is the first thing I remove in any new rails app and I've never had this problem. You're right that if you omit those tags you will have broken JavaScript though.

Comment: I added the turbolinks links stuff and get the same result

application.html.erb:
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

also added to gem file and install gems.

Comment: it is passing the data through as a parameter in the URL

Comment: do you have all your requires in application.js?

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.facebox
//= require event_calendar
//= require_tree .

Comment: try this

<%=link_to "Delete", :action => 'destroy_password',method: :delete, :id => p.id, :job => @job, data: {confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete this password?'} %>

Comment: still passes as param
Started GET "/project/destroy_password?data%5Bconfirm%5D=Are+you+sure+you+want+to+delete+this+password%3F&id=9158&job=1073&method=delete" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-04 09:21:14 -0700

Comment: last try:
<%=link_to "Delete", :action => 'destroy_password', :id => p.id, :job => @job, :onclick =>"return confirm('Are you sure?')" %>

try this

Comment: no go, it passes the onclick as a param Started GET "/project/destroy_password?id=21307&job=1076&onclick=return+confirm%28%27Are+you+sure%3F%27%29"

Comment: ok another try, i think this might work! 

<%=link_to "Delete", {:action => 'destroy_password', :id => p.id, :job => @job},:method => :delete ,data: {confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete this password?'} %>

Comment: That did it!. Thanks!

I removed the turbolinks stuff that was suggested and it still works!

Comment: the problem was that u were mentioning everything as the action :P 

mark as solved :)